# Developing inside a container on a remote Docker host

Tags: vscode-remote

From my Windows 10 machine I am trying to develop using containers on a remote Ubuntu 18.04 host. I have been following this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_developing-inside-a-container-on-a-remote-docker-host

Locally I am running:

- VSCode Version: 1.44.2 (user setup) OS
- Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
- Docker Extension 1.1.0
- Remote Container Extension 0.112.0
- Remote SSH Extension 0.51.0
- Docker cli is installed (via Chocolatey)

In settings I have set:

```
"docker.host": "ssh://simon@myhost",
```

Remote host is running Docker and has other containers running. I can also ssh to it in VSCode without issue.

From VSCode I have tried to do "Remote Containers: Open Folder in Container", as well as the Workspace and Repo variants. But nothing happens. I've looked through the Output logs - I'm not certain which one I should be looking at but I've been through all and can't see anything relevant.

The closest I have got is using "Remote Containers: Try a sample", selecting .Net Core. In the bottom right I can see a message saying "Starting with Dev Container". But nothing happens.

The guide I linked to above doesn't really step through the process very well. Does anyone have a better guide, or know of what logs I should be looking at?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/ssh

Basically Docker cli can only connect to a remote server over ssh using keys (passwords are not supported).

Following the above document I configured ssh keys and I can now connect using the clone repository option.